# Laravel 8 laravel change language in url

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I've been searching a lot and trying a lot of tutorials, and I haven't been able to get it to work.
The case, is that I want to set the language in each request that I send through the url, since I operate through an API, so, in each call, the language parameters would be sent like this "localhost/public/api/en/createuser", I have followed this tutorial, which does what I need, but at least in laravel 8 has not worked.

https://irando.co.id/articles/how-to-use-language-slug-in-laravel-url-and-set-directions

Comment: what isn't working?

Comment: May be this [link](https://devnote.in/how-to-create-laravel-localization/) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should add prefix to top of the api routes. For example;

```
use App\Libraries\DetectLanguage;
    
Route::prefix(DetectLanguage::setLanguageCodeByPrefix())->group(function () { 
  /* your routes in api.php */ 
}
```

DetectLanguage must have setLanguageCodeByPrefix() method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries\DetectLanguage;

class DetectLanguage
{

   public static setLanguageCodeByPrefix()
   {
      $languagePrefix = request()->segment(1); // For example en

      // You can use this define any area in code
      define('REQUEST_LANGUAGE', $languagePrefix);

      return $languagePrefix;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed solution provided by your link
https://irando.co.id/articles/how-to-use-language-slug-in-laravel-url-and-set-directions

and edit the following code in RouteServiceProvider.php and it works

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {

        $locale = \Request::segment(1);
        app()->setLocale($locale);

        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->prefix($locale)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
}
```